# configure and inherit top link navigation for site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, navigation

I Have a bunch of site collections in SharePoint online and I want them to have the same top navigation links. Is it possible to configure this in some way that they inherit the navigation form the root site collection? If yes is it possible to configure the top link navigation of the root site collection using Powershell in SharPoint online?

The other idea I had is to configure the top link navigation of every site collection separately. Is this possible using Powershell? I know it is possible in SharePoint 2013 how ever using SharePoint online seems to work a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For site collections to have the navigation from the root site collection set  $spWebNavigation.UseShared = $true as shown below :

```
 # get the site collection
 $spSite = Get-SPOSite -Identity "http://sitecollection"
        # loop through all the webs in the site collection
 foreach ($spWeb in $spSite.AllWebs)
  {
    # check if root web as this one doesn't obviously inherit
     if (!$spWeb.IsRootWeb)
     {
        # grab a Navigation object
        $spWebNavigation = $spWeb.Navigation
        # change to true
        $spWebNavigation.UseShared = $true
     }

     $spWeb.Dispose()
   }

   $spSite.Dispose()
```

Comment: And follow these steps to use PowerShell Online:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fp161372(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What does $spSite.AllWebs do? Does it get all the sub sites? This does not give my anything if I called it in Powershell using a sit collection with one sub site. It also does not exist in the auto completion of ISE. I am using the Powershell according to the instructions above. do I have to load something in to Powershell beforehand to make the script work?

Comment: Also the problem is that I am trying to have the same navigation as the root site collection on different site collection not for sub sites inheriting from the root site.

Comment: you are using sharepoint online management shell  ?

Comment: yes, using SharePoint online management shell

Comment: Then need to use CSOM for that refer this http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-Get-a-19cfb449